# iText: Add table to all document pages

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, document

How to add table (pdfptable) with something content (text, logo etc) to all pdf-document pages after he was created (using iText with c#)? Is it possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are going to have to use the stamper class. here is an example from the  [official website](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=120)